# Splitting an integer into smaller integers

Tags: python, split, integer

I have a number which I want to split into smaller numbers of equal length.
Suppose, I have the number 212313454
I, now want to split it into 3 numbers of 3 digits each:
 212, 313 and 454

What if I want to randomly split it? I mean
212313454 into
213, 354, 114
Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Try something! You can do it with arithmetic, or with string operations.

Answer (score 3):

You can use modulus operator `%` and division operator `/` and form the divisor as `10^n` where n is number of digits in each result of split.

Comment: Or divmod is a little more efficient than % combined with /.

Answer (score 2):

Convert them to a string and then split them. Like:

```
s = str(212313454)
a = s[0:3]
b = s[3:6]
c = s[6:]
```

Use a loop for a variable length number.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to ask but your question is vague (yes I know people have "answered" the question...).

- "split [a number] into smaller numbers of equal length". Your example and hence everyone's answers assume you just have 9 decimal digits and want three smaller integers back, but what if you have a longer or shorter number, or want more/less subdivisions?
- and randomly splitting "212313454 into 213, 354, 114". What is the correlation of these smaller numbers with the larger # exactly? 213 isn't in 212313454 if my eyes are working properly. If you want to pick random digits from an integer you can do that.

Lastly if you are just experimenting for fun, cool, but you should think a bit about making integers into strings and back and forth. A lot of math routines in python you should checkout are in the standard library, e.g. math module, random module, and bitwise operators too.

Answer (score 0):

Im not going to write the code for you but here is a simple way to do it:

- Make the int a string
- split the string each 3 characters
- once you do that iterate the list and turn the strings back into ints

I think you can figure it out if you try!

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to convert the integer to a string adn then change it back to int again...
Here is how I would do...

**Code:**

```
c = 212313454

def splits(c,length):
    l = [c[i:i+3] for i in range(0,len(c),3)]
    print map(int,l)

if __name__=='__main__':
    splits(str(c),3)
```

**Output:**

```
[212, 313, 454]
```

Hope this helps :)